How to use Config vars of Heroku in Salesforce standalone NodeJS LWR SPA?
I deployed my standalone NodeJS LWR SPA to Heroku.
To deal with sensitive data, I need to set config vars in Heroku dashboard, and use it in code.
I have added a key-value fair like this:
TEST: test.
In nodejs, Heroku document says I need to use like this:
process.env.TEST

However, in the heroku app, when I tried to get the process.env.TEST value, it says undefined instead of 'test'.
